# Can Firestore experience any sort of hotspotting from reads?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Nothing in the usage and limits documentation warns against a collection or a document being read too often; however, I've read about read-hotspotting in NoSQL. Can Firestore experience any sort of hotspotting (or other ill effects) from too many reads hitting a single collection or document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [hotspotting behavior is very well documented](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#hotspots).

> Avoid high read or write rates to lexicographically close documents,
>   or your application will experience contention errors. This issue is
>   known as hotspotting, and your application can experience hotspotting
>   if it does any of the following:
>
> - Creates new documents at a very high rate and allocates its own monotonically increasing IDs.
> - Cloud Firestore allocates document IDs using a scatter algorithm. You should not encounter hotspotting on writes if you create new
>     documents using automatic document IDs.
> - Creates new documents at a high rate in a collection with few documents.
> - Creates new documents with a monotonically increasing field, like a timestamp, at a very high rate.
> - Deletes documents in a collection at a high rate.
> - Writes to the database at a very high rate without gradually increasing traffic.